# How to access NavigationController.PushViewController under UITableViewSource?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

How can I access `NavigationController` inside `UITableviewSource` class?

On Row selection I want to navigate to another `UIController`.

This is my code,

```
public class RootTableSource : UITableViewSource
{
    IList<VendorDetails> tableItems;
    string cellIdentifier = "UIViewController";

    ReportsList reportList;
    AddNewReport addnewReport;

    public RootTableSource()
    {
    }

    public RootTableSource (IEnumerable<VendorDetails> items)
    {
        tableItems = items.ToList (); 
    }

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); 

        // Redirect to another UIController....
    }

    public VendorDetails GetItem (int id)
    {
        return tableItems [id];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this is by passing a reference to the TableViewController when I create my Source.  Then the Source can use this reference to access it's parent's NavigationController.

```
UITableViewController _parent;

public RootTableSource (IEnumerable<VendorDetails> items, UITableViewController parent)
{
    tableItems = items.ToList (); 
    _parent = parent;
}


public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); 

    _parent.NavigationController.PushViewController(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you instance UINavigationController in AppDelegate ?

like this...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationViewController;
```

then you should can access UINavigationController from AppDelegate delegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation yourClassName

-(void)functionName{

    AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    appdelegate.navigationViewController;  //your UINavigationController

    [appdelegate.navigationViewController pushViewController:yourUIViewController animated:YES];

}

@end
```

wish help ~

### edit:

Sorry i have never use Xamarin before

so i think this is a bad way to implement ...

but it look work

#### AppDelegates.cs

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{

    UIWindow window;
    HomeScreen home;
    public static UINavigationController navigation;
    //set navigation public and static      

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        home = new HomeScreen ();
        navigation = new UINavigationController(home);
        window.RootViewController =  navigation;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### yourClassName.cs

```
AppDelegate.navigation
//access navigation
```

wish help again ...

Comment: Sorry, I am using C# with Xamarin. I dont have idea on objective C. Will you please help me to have it on xamarin?

Comment: Sorry i not notice you use the Xamarin and i never it use before .... so i install Xamarin and play a while ...

Comment: Hey I tried to your code but I am getting object reference not set to instance of an object.

Comment: Hey my problem is different in this case.
I want to navigate from  Row selected event to another UIView controller.
I am not able to do this .
Plz help.

Comment: Please edit your question or post a new one with more specified information.